# Nsight Debugging using single GPU

Tags: cuda, nsight

I have a single GPU in my Windows 7 system. Would like to debug my gpu code locally on this machine.

There is a confusion regarding this. Do I need to do headless debugging, (may be making my on-board display as display driver), as explained in [Setup Local Headless GPU Debugging](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/desktop/setup_local_headless_debugging.htm)?

Or do I need not do any thing like that?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do local headless debugging with only a single GPU.  Headless means there is no monitor or active display attached to the GPU that is running the code under debug.  If you are debugging locally, you need this display to see the nsight GUI and your windows desktop.

Single GPU local (non-headless) debugging is covered in the nsight [manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/desktop/setup_local_debugging.htm%3FTocPath%3DDeveloper%2520Tools%7CDesktop%2520Developer%2520Tools%7CNVIDIA%2520Nsight%2520Visual%2520Studio%2520Edition%7CNVIDIA%2520Nsight%2520Visual%2520Studio%2520Edition%25204.1%7CInstallation%2520and%2520Setup%2520Essentials%7CTarget%2520and%2520Host%2520Setup%7C_____4).

If you can enable another GPU (need not be an NVIDIA GPU), then you can use that GPU for your windows display, and do headless debugging on the NVIDIA GPU.